# Shorthand for x ? x : y

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

Is there a shorthand for `x ? x : y`? A relatively tame example:

```
def find_or_create_by_name(name)
    self.find_by_name(name) ? self.find_by_name(name) : self.create(name)
end
```

Of course I could do something like

```
def find_or_create_by_name(name)
    x = self.find_by_name(name)
    x ? x : self.create(name)
end
```

but then I'm starting to lose the space I've saved with the ternary operator in the first place. (and if I use a full `if` statement, the same redundancy would occur.

Comment: The shorthand for `x ? x : y` is `x || y` for nearly all not esoteric languages.

Comment: It looks like Rails.

Comment: Take a look at Rails' [`find_or_create_by`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L163-L165) (hint: it's `find_by(...) || create(...)`)

Comment: Note that `find_by_name(name) ? find_by_name(name) : create(name)` is in general not be the same as `x = find_by_name(name); 
x ? x : create(name)`. Suppose, for example, `@tot = 0; def find_by_name(name); @tot += 1; name; end`. In the first case, `@tot #=> 2`, in the second, `@tot #=> 1`. Note that  `self.` is not needed, even if it were used by the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use `||` operator:

```
def find_or_create_by_name(name)
  find_by_name(name) || create(name)
end
```

Comment: @JonathanTuzman: it is going to return `find_by_name(name)` if it is present (not nil nor false) or `create(name)` otherwise

Comment: @JonathanTuzman In Ruby, `a || b` never returns a boolean object (`true` or `false`) unless the object `a` and/or `b` is indeed a boolean (`true` or `false`, or in other words an instance of `TrueClass` or `FalseClass`).